# jquery offset value not getting new height created from onload animation

Tags: jquery

I am using `.offset();` to calculate a value from top in a variable...

```
pos = content.offset();
```

But my problem is I have a animation that runs when a twitter api loads.

So this means there is about a 2-5 second delay on this animation before it fires. This animation increases my `content = $("#slider-container")` height (by about 64px). But sometimes if twitter never loads, then the animation will never run.

So when this variable is being used in my script below, it gets the offset value from before the twitter animation. Even when the animation has run.

As you can see - my second script, this is my twitter animation that runs when the tweet loads - and `$('#tweetbar')` is inside `$("#slider-container")`

How can I sort this?

My script...

```
$(window).bind("resize.browsersize", function() {

    var $tabs = $('#left-tab, #right-tab'),
        positionScroll = $(window).height() / 2,
        content = $("#slider-container"),
        pos = content.offset();

    $(window).scroll(function(){  

        if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= pos.top + 265 - positionScroll  ) {

            if ($(window).scrollTop() + positionScroll <= pos.top + content.height() - $tabs.height()) {

                $tabs.removeAttr('style').css({ position:'fixed', top: positionScroll + 'px'}); 

            } else {

                $tabs.removeAttr('style').css({
                    top: content.height() - $tabs.height()
                });

            }

        } else {

            $tabs.removeAttr('style').css({ top: '265px' });    

        }

    }); 

}).trigger("resize.browsersize");
```

---

My animation script...

```
$("#tweetbar").tweet({
    username: "twitter",
    join_text: "auto",
    count: 1,
    auto_join_text_default: "we said,",
    auto_join_text_ed: "we",
    auto_join_text_ing: "we were",
    auto_join_text_reply: "we replied to",
    auto_join_text_url: "we were checking out",
    loading_text: "loading tweets..."
}).bind("loaded", function(){

    $('#tweetbar').slideDown();

});
```

Comment: Is it not possible to update the value of pos when the twitter api loads?

Comment: Would that overide the existing values?

Comment: Are you asking if you can change the value of a variable?

Comment: I think its because I am using the var inside a browser resize function - and the values not being global - I am needing to update the value of the variable yes